# .svnignore ignored by Subversion when doing: "svn copy"

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have the following (Windows command) Subversion script:

```
svn propset svn:ignore --recursive -F .svnignore .

echo Ignoring files with the following filename patterns:
svn propget svn:ignore

svn copy %sourceUrl% %destUrl%
```

This is what I get running it:

```
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
property 'svn:ignore' set on '1'
property 'svn:ignore' set on '1\A'
property 'svn:ignore' set on '1\B'
property 'svn:ignore' set on '2'
...
Ignoring files with the following filename patterns:

TempDir
*.o
*.obj

Committing transaction...
Committed revision 79.
```

The copy operation is successful, however the files that should have been ignored have been copied, too.

The `.svnignore` file has been picked correctly, as shown in the output. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please, re-read relevant [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) fully and understand

   - purpose,
   - usage
   - limitation

of svn:ignore property

For convenience and speed, I'll quote the most important parts in the topic, but the **full understanding** of all details from your side is still **required**

**P. 1**

> When found on a versioned directory, the `svn:ignore` property is
>   expected to contain a list of newline-delimited file patterns that
>   Subversion should use to determine ignorable objects in *that same*
>   directory.

and I can't predict directory of your `%sourceUrl%`

**P. 2**

(most important and applicable in your case)

> Subversion's support for ignorable file patterns extends *only* to the
>   one-time process of adding unversioned files and directories to
>   version control. **Once an object is under Subversion's control, the
>   ignore pattern mechanisms no longer apply to it.** In other words,
>   don't expect Subversion to avoid committing changes you've made to a
>   versioned file simply because that file's name matches an ignore
>   pattern — Subversion *always* notices all of its versioned objects.

Comment: "to determine ignorable objects in that same directory": shouldn't the `--recursive` argument make the ignore patterns work on the whole subdirectory tree?

Comment: @Pietro - yes, mea culpa.

Comment: "Once an object is under Subversion's control, the ignore pattern mechanisms no longer apply to it" - If I `delete` (e.g. from TortoiseSVN) %destUrl%, update the `.svnignore` file, and run `svn copy...` again, will the new `.svnignore` be used by SVN?

Comment: @Pietro - `.svnignore` per se **not used** by SVN. svn:ignore work only for `svn add` + `svn st`. If %sourceUrl% is versioned file, %destUrl% will be versioned too

Comment: You mean that `svn copy` does not take `.svnignore` into account?